# mptfs disconnects after a while - using alcatel onetouch idol 3 and ubuntu 17.04

Tags: usb, android, mtp, smartphone

In order to access my smartphone storage I installed mtpfs.

As soon as I connect the usb plug, and Android option appears in files, allowing me to choose between internal storage and sd card

Everything works well, but after a while files freezes, I can no longer access any file in the smartphone, and I have to unplug and plug it again to see the drive.

Anybody else is having a similar issue?

Using ubuntu 17.04 with an alcatel onetouch idol 3 4.7 (6039A)

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.10.0-20-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:22:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo dpkg -l mtpfs
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name            Version      Architecture Description
+++-===============-============-============-===================================
ii  mtpfs           1.1-5        amd64        FUSE filesystem for Media Transfer
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: the problem is inherent to MTP, it persist on all OSes, be it GNU/Linux, Mac, or Windows, and there is nothing you can do about it as far as I know. But there are better ways to access your phone — e.g. to setup a FTP server on the phone and use it through WiFi, or to mount the phone through adbfs.

---

I do have *Alcatel Onetouch idol2*. Earlier I've had some Samsung, and now I've also got as a gift *Galaxy J1 mini*.

With disregard to a phone, MTP have always been very bad. Long loading and sudden disconnections are something in common. It got me curious, what's the deal.

I am still yet to find the technical reasons behind it being so bad. As I understood, MTP is very crippled protocol, e.g. [it only supports read or write whole file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol#History), no partial reads/writes. But the upside of the approach is being very simple — and I have no idea how it could've been screwed up so bad.

Out of reading different threads *(see e.g. [this one, it's huge](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2811kx/mtp_is_such_a_bad_way_of_transferring_files_that/))* I've got a few things:

1. MTP problems are irrelevant to the host OS. GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, Windows — everyone is susceptible.
2. If you really want to work in some way with your phone, you'd have to either setup a FTP server *(and I bet you can browse files in file manager through sftp protocol)*, or to enable adb filesystem.

I went the adb filesystem way. You'd have to:

1. Enable "usb debugging" on your phone *(the how-to depends on the phone, it's either straight in settings, or hidden behind a fighting-game-like super combo, like click n times a label to activate)*.
2. `sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev android-tools-adb`
3. Build and install [adbfs-rootless](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless).
4. Now you can browse the phone. Connect it, and type in the computer terminal `mkdir mnt`, `adbfs mnt`.
5. It's not yet mounted — look up the phone screen, it should ask if you "allow connection from the device <some_id>". Click "always allow from <this_id>".

Now the phone is mounted under `./mnt`, so you can browse it. To unmount execute `fusermount -u mnt` *(it's FUSE, you don't need elevated privileges)*.

It's not really ideal, e.g. for moving a file using Dolphin, I got once "disk is full". Ultimately it's a problem with Dolphin, though it had a reason — when I used instead `mv` command, there were warnings about impossibility to set permissions. They're harmless though *(unless perhaps you do care of permissions on the phone)*. But I bet sftp would be more seamless.

I think you could also write a udev rule to auto-mount *(a?)* phone on connection, but I didn't have enough motivation to explore that.